# How to get the numbers where the binary representation is 1?

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary

I am trying to implement some fast binary exponentiation in python. I want to know the integers the binary representation of the number is returning 1. Maybe an example will be clearer:

```py
bin(13) # returns 1101 because one 8 + one 4 + one 1 = 13.
```

How can I build a function that returns 8,4,1 passing the binary number as an argument? As you can see, I am not explicitly trying to get powers of 2 but the minimalist representation to multiply the powers together.

Comment: I don't actually know python so I won't post an answer but in c you could do something like `for (int bit = 1; bit; bit <<= 1) if (number & bit) { /*append value of bit to an array or string or whatever */ }` substituting int for whatever type number is. So if you know how to express that in Python that'd work.

Comment: Interesting. Appending the value each bit where it equals one seems a bit slow to me. I will take a look.

Comment: It's the only way (well, other approaches would still be similar) to do it concisely. Your other option if you need blinding speed could be a precalculated lookup table where `bitValues[number]` is an array of values for the given number. But that's only really feasible if `number` is 8-bits. If it's 16-bits you might have cache miss issues because of the size of the table but you'd just have to test, really. If it's 32 or 64 bits then a table is just too large although I guess you could divide it into 4/8 8-bit chunks.

Comment: I need to worry about performance for my type of problem, but you definitely helped me :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I decompose a number into powers of 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30226094/how-do-i-decompose-a-number-into-powers-of-2)

Comment: What are you trying to do, that performance is important enough to justify micro-optimisations but _not_ important enough to justify using something other than Python? Why are you using `bin()`, which is just a binary string representation of a number? I’m guessing that you may be doing all this for the sake of learning?

Comment: Definitely not a duplicate. I cannot say exactly what I am trying to do, but let's just say I need python for easy-to-use integration. I am learning and love to learn. As I said it had to do with optimizing exponentiation. A lot of micro-optimizations will lead to macro-optimization, right? ;)

Comment: Nevermind, the question I asked is a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is a bit perplexing (see my comment), but I wanted to share a solution anyway because the currently accepted answer seems baffling to me. For the sake of curiosity, I may compare and benchmark a bunch of different solutions tomorrow.

```py
bin_num = bin(13)

def bin_str_decomp(bin_num_str):
    bin_clean = bin_num_str[:1:-1]
    return [1 << idx for idx, bit in enumerate(bin_clean) if bit == '1']

print(bin_str_decomp(bin_num))
```

Comment: I do like how much cleaner your solution is. Good work.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something alone these lines:

```py
# Split the binary and grab interested part, and its size.
# >> bin(123456789) == "0b111010110111100110100010101"
binary = bin(123456789)[2:]
size = len(binary)

numbers = []
for i in range(size):
    # Checks to see if the binary[i] is not equals to zero.
    if binary[i] is not "0":
        # Indexes the `binary` string and adds (size - i - 1) zeros to the end of it.
        number = int(binary[i] + "0" * (size - i - 1), 2)
        numbers.append(number)


print(numbers)
# >> [67108864, 33554432, 16777216, 4194304, 1048576, 524288, 131072, 65536, 32768, 16384, 2048, 1024, 256, 16, 4, 1]
```

Here is a shorter solution for the heck of it.

```py
binary = bin(13)[2:]

nums = [
    int(binary[i] + "0" * (len(binary) - i - 1), 2)
    for i in range(len(binary))
    if binary[i] is not "0"
]
return nums
```

Here is the single line solution, for the heck of it as well.

```py
print((lambda binary: [int(binary[i] + "0" * (len(binary) - i - 1), 2) for i in range(len(binary)) if binary[i] is not "0"])(binary = bin(123456789)[2:]))
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201806/discussion-on-answer-by-felipe-faria-how-to-get-where-the-binary-representation).

Comment: @SamuelLiew How do you do that? I would love the ability to move comments into a chat, or at the very least create a chat and import the existing comments. I'm guessing that it is something you unlock at higher reputation?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile oops, I didn't notice you already created a chatroom earlier. Anyway when a mod creates a chatroom, all commenters are granted the ability to chat even if they do not have enough reputation. If comments get too chatty next time just flag the post to request a mod move them to chat.